# How do I detect a grsecurity kernel?

Tags: kernel, grsecurity

How can I detect whether my kernel is/has/enables grsecurity? I'm using an official Ubuntu Bionic [image](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/), and I'm trying to establish whether [another Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27262629/96588) is relevant for me.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
paxtest
```

or

```
grep PaX /proc/pid/status
```

Comment: `paxtest` is not installed, and `/proc/pid/status` does not exist. Did you mean a specific PID?

Comment: `grep PaX /proc/1/status`